# How come comment flags are not listed in the flagging summary?

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

I realize comments are not as important as questions or answers, but since they're included in your flagging history, shouldn't they also be listed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike deleted posts, deleted comments are simply gone. While the devs are able to see all of that, not even moderators are able to track the placement of deleted comments.

Thus, unlike posts which you can link to even post-deletion, there isn't anything to link to when it comes to deleted comments. There's no trace at all of it to even know what was flagged. Since it would be awkward to only show live comments (i.e. failed flags), then it only makes sense to not display comments at all in the report.

Like comments in comparison to posts, comment flags are second-fiddle to the other forms of flagging (and are even only responsible for half as much influence). So they pretty much get shafted in the summary.

Comment: This is out of date