# are comment flags supposed to be non-traceable?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comment-flags, flag-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How come comment flags are not listed in the flagging summary?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85203/how-come-comment-flags-are-not-listed-in-the-flagging-summary)

when flagging a question or answer that action is traceable / visible by clicking on your flag count in your profile view. comment flags are never listed here but they are present in the summary on the right (just a total count, no individual flags). is this by design? I was hoping to be able to see the comments I flagged and navigate there.

Comment: @YannisRizos: It's not an up-to-date dupe though, no? Mods *can* now see deleted comments, so it sorta makes Anna's answer moot?

Comment: @Matt Grace != Anna ;P Now although moderators can see deleted comments, regular users still can't, so the reasoning stands, where would the link under the flag take you? From a user's perspective, if the flag was actioned and the comment deleted.

Comment: @YannisRizos I can understand the absence of a link when a flag is actioned and the comment deleted, maybe I should have been more specific: I cannot understand the absence of a link when (a flag hasn't been actioned *yet* and) the comment still exists, and also: why are comment flags not listed at all (even without a link, which I would find perfectly acceptable when the flag has been actioned).

Comment: Why? What purpose would the link serve, other than satisfy your curiosity? Comments are third class citizens, and comment flags are extremely unimportant...

Comment: I guess you're right, except it wasn't to satisfy my curiosity, I was trying to navigate back to the post I flagged a comment on because I realized I wanted to make a contribution to the topic (and I didn't have my browsing history anymore either). oh well.