# More informative flagging history for comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, declined-flags, comment-flags, flag-history

When we enter the flagging history for our account through the number link in our profile, we get a nice list of flagged questions/answers, and on the right a summary of the number of helpful, disputed, declined flags.

I would like to see a special tab for the history of comment flags, or even have them interspersed between the other flags.

This request arises because I like my flags to be as helpful as possible (don't we all?) and I would like to be able to see which flags are declined, so that I can e.g. ask around for the reasoning behind that. This is especially relevant since my answer and question flags are all deemed helpful (save one, which was accidentally denied and a follow-up custom flag dealt with it), but I regularly have one of my comment flags denied.

---

I am aware that this request has been filed in the past, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120617) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85203).

The first of those does not address my point because it dates from before even the total tallies on the comment flags were displayed. The second is downright incorrect according to [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90112#comment268280_90112) from a few months later.

Besides that the answers in above references seem no longer applicable or otherwise suboptimal, e.g. [this excerpt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145905/222340):

> Then check the places where you had flagged comments:
>
> If the comment disappeared, your flag was (most likely) deemed helpful.
> If the comment is still there, but there is no flag icon when you hover over it, your flag is still pending for review.
> If the comment is still there and the flag icon is shown on hover, your flag has been declined.

suggests that *I* keep track of which posts I flagged. I think it gives worthless advice; memorizing things should be left with computers and not clutter my more severely limited head-space.

---

*Edit -- 17-05-2013:*

I have since localized three further questions ([this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119413), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135528) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119764)) with basically the same suggestion. None of these received any response from official channels. Any particular reason for this? I understand comments are "ephemeral" "second-class citizens", but what's wrong with more feedback on one's efforts to help the community in this aspect?

---

*Edit -- 29-06-2013:*

The update that enables this has gone live on all of StackExchange. This request may therefore be marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). Your work is much appreciated, SE devs!

Comment: There are hundreds, if not thousands, of open feature requests. We can't expect the team to respond to them all. You're talking about a pretty big change here so it has a long way ahead of it, even in the optimistic case the team will pick it up for implementation.

Comment: [I hate you.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230953/171857)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Jarrod and Oded are performing a very large refactor of how flags are stored in the database as I write this, hopefully going live in the next week or two.  It's a *huge* set of changes, a multi-month project (which is pretty damn rare around here).

Once that goes live we'll take another look at this.  As it stands those comment flags are stored in an entirely different database table, so including them would be a mess.  The refactor centralizes all flags, so having a view that includes some data about them is much more doable, if it makes sense to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I guess it makes sense to postpone any definite decision about this until after said refactor has gone live. Should I just edit this question a few weeks after this is done to bring it to the SE team's attention again?

Comment: @Lord_Farinthat sounds like a fine plan, it should begin rolling out end of this week or beginning of next...we're finishing the migration code now.  My first todo after the girls are off here is to look over all the SQL migrations actually :)

Comment: It seems that the changes have been implemented on all sites now (I noticed them on MSO a few days earlier). Thanks, good work! This question can be marked status-complete as far as I'm concerned.